# Найти css у элемента

Tags: jquery, css, javascript

Вот есть такой код - мне нужно поменять css у всплывающей картинки - но его ни как не могу найти - где он???
там есть конечно jquery.fancybox.css, но там идёт речь об #fancybox а у элементов в индексе id="yt" - как так?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Приветственное всплывающее окно | pcvector.net</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.0/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="http://yandex.st/jquery/fancybox/1.3.4/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css"/>

</head>

<BODY>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openFancybox() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#yt').trigger('click');
    }, 500);
};
$(document).ready(function () {
    var visited = $.cookie('visited');
    if (visited == 'yes') {
        return false; // second page load, cookie active
    } else {
        openFancybox(); // first page load, launch fancybox
    }
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes', {
        expires: 7 // the number of days cookie  will be effective
    });
    $("#yt").click(function () {
        $.fancybox({
            href: this.href,
            type: "image"
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script> 
<a id="yt" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s22.jpg" alt=""/></a> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/firebug/ - как вариант

Comment: ))) пробывал, не смог всё же найти

Answer (score 1):

А ссылку на страницу дать было нельзя?
В любом случаи у вас больше никаких css-файлов не подключено так что ищите в jquery.fancybox.css

Comment: http://cl307938.tmweb.ru/
да, но объясните мне, что нужно в цсс править?

Comment: Замечательно вы, однако, вопросы задаете.
> что нужно в цсс править
А что вы хотите в итоге получить? То и правьте. И да картинки там нет